# Haskell RSA crypto random generator type

Tags: haskell, random, cryptography, rsa

My goal is to generate a keypair using `generateKeyPair` from `Codec.Crypto.RSA`.

This function requires a generator of type `RandomGen`. I have tried to make this generator with `newGenIO`, but I'm having a hard time specifying its type.

```
import qualified Codec.Crypto.RSA as Crypto
import Crypto.Random

someFunc = do
  let g = newGenIO :: CryptoRandomGen (IO SystemRandom)
  let keyPair = Crypto.generateKeyPair g 10
```

Haskell suggested `CryptoRandomGen SystemRandom` when I didn't specify a type after `newGenIO`.

This is the error message that comes when trying to run the code.

```
    • Expected a type, but
      ‘CryptoRandomGen (IO SystemRandom)’ has kind
      ‘Constraint’
```

Does anyone know what type I have use to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing that line with this one:

```
  g <- newGenIO :: IO SystemRandom
```

When you want a specific instance of a class, you just use the type, rather than specifying the class again. And to get something out of IO, you need to bind into it rather than just using `=`.